# Why can browsers only download two or four components in parallel?

Tags: performance, http, httprequest, yahoo

I know that reducing the number of HTTP requests decreases the page load time for users because browsers can only load "[two or four](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/28/performance-research-part-1/)" components in parallel per host name.

But I can't seem to find information anywhere about WHY browsers can only download "two or four" components in parallel per host name!? Is this a limitation of the browsers of HTTP?

Comment: I think it's a deliberate decision to avoid spamming a single web site with very many connections at once, i.e. it's enforced by the browsers themselves.

Comment: see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections AND http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's covered in [RFC 2616, "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1"](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> Clients that use persistent connections SHOULD limit the number of simultaneous connections that they maintain to a given server. A single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with any server or proxy. A proxy SHOULD use up to 2*N connections to another server or proxy, where N is the number of simultaneously active users. These guidelines are intended to improve HTTP response times and avoid congestion.

You've also got to remember this RFC was written in 1999, in a day where we had far less powerful servers, networking kit etc.

Most browsers now support more than two connections with six being very common.

See http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network if you want an up-to-date list of the number of parallel connections to a hostname that browsers support.

You might also want to read-up some of Jim Getty's stuff on 'buffer bloat' which parallel connections can make worse.

Comment: Thanks - that link was just what I was looking for! Surprised there isn't more readily available information regarding this (maybe I just wasn't looking hard enough)

Comment: I also find it a little strange that HTTP/1.1 (which as you mentioned, is now very old) hasn't really been improved upon much at all in the last decade. I'm surprised there aren't master plans for HTTP/2 (well, if there are I can't seem to find them) surely HTTP/1.1 really doesn't suite the needs of web users today?

Comment: It's being discussed but changing it won't be easy - have a look at [http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2012JanMar/thread.html](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2012JanMar/thread.html) & [http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2012AprJun/thread.html](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2012AprJun/thread.html) for current discussions